# Reference for most up to date sport physiology

Tags: human-physiology, exercise

I currently have

> Exercise Physiology Nutrition Energy And Human Performance, 7th Edition, 2012, McArdle et al.

as my reference book for Exercise physiology. However, based on a question I recently asked here on this very same board, I realise the book sometimes takes shortcuts and does not provide a complete explanation. Plus, the structure is sometimes a bit difficult or not to my liking.

I saw that the 8th edition (2014) has been issued. I don't know if it is significantly different from the edition I have.

Would someone have another solid reference for Exercise physiology? I am particularly interested in the energy pathways and their training.